# Spring AOP: Passing parameters into target method: params null. Why?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I've created an Spring aspect to do authorization for a GraphQL api. My intent is to have the aspect read all the to-be-passed-in parameters, validate the user, and then inject in a newly user object as an additional parameter and then call the original target method. Unfortunately, seem that all my joinPoint arguments and parameters are sadly null.

**Aspect Method**
(being called, but joinPoint args and params are null)

```
@Around("@annotation(Authorize)")
public Object authorize(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    List<Object> arguments = Arrays.asList(joinPoint.getArgs()); // null[]
    if (userAuthenticated() == true) arguments.add(loggedInUser); // crash
        return joinPoint.proceed(arguments.toArray());
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Why? and how do I overcome this?

**GraphQL target method**
(note that I popped in User at the end of the method params)

```
@Authorize({Right.ORGANISATION_LIST, Right.ORGANISATION_VIEW})
@GraphQLQuery(name="partners")
public PartnersPage listPartners(@GraphQLArgument(name = "pageNo") Integer pageNo, @GraphQLArgument(name = "pageSize") Integer pageSize, @GraphQLArgument(name="sortBy") String sortBy, @GraphQLArgument(name="searchBy") String searchBy, @GraphQLArgument(name="searchRegex") String searchRegex, User user) {

    PartnersPage partnersPage = new PartnersPage();
    Query q = QueryHelper.build(pageNo, pageSize, sortBy, searchBy, searchRegex);
    partnersPage.setOrganisations(mongoTemplate.find(q, Organisation.class));

    return partnersPage;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `null[]`? That `joinPoint.getArgs()` returns `null`? And: how is the original client code calling the method if you inject an additional parameter into it?

Comment: You have 7.5k reputation and should be able to describe your problem better. Your question is quite unclear. In addition to @daniu's question, what does the comment "crash" mean? What does "popped in User at the end" mean? Why are you converting an array to a List and back to an array? Can you show how and with which parameters `listPartners(..)` is getting called? Furthermore, it is impossible that `joinPoint.getArgs()` for this method is `null`. Many open questions.